# Drop down navigation in fluid design, getting overflow when page resized

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, fluid-layout

I'm having a hard time with my fluid design's navigation. When I shrink the page, the links fall under the black bar I've designated for them. If i say,

```
    overflow: hidden;
```

Then my drop downs get hidden as well as the necessary links at the end of the nav. It gets more complicated, I think, because of the drop down menus.

Does anyone know what I could do to resize the nav bar with my page, while keeping all of the links visible with their drop downs?

here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pFQhm/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem stems from using `float:left;` to create your horizontal menu. Using `float:left;` requires you to use `overflow:hidden;` in order to have a dynamic height navigation, as you already noted.

The alternative is to use `display:inline-block;` instead of `float:left;` in order to cause your menu items to line up horizontally. Having done that, the rest is really simple.

[Here's a basic example of a navigation system using `display:inline-block;`](http://jsfiddle.net/3Z7FS/2/)

So, in your situation, you would:

1. Remove `min-width` from `#top_menu`
2. Remove defined `height` from `#top_menu`
3. Remove `float:left;` from `#top_menu li`
4. Change `display:block;` to `display:inline-block;` on `#top_menu li`
5. Style as desired

The navigation items now wrap as needed, while still maintaining the visibility of the menus.

[And here's a jsFiddle with your code, modified as suggested.](http://jsfiddle.net/vkGYx/)